# Power View Fails to Connect

Tags: sql-server, ssas, tabular, powerview

When I try to create a Pover View report over my  .bism connection I get following error:

Original XML

> rsCannotRetrieveModel400An error
>   occurred while loading the model for the item or data source
>   'http://localhost/rpl/model.bism'. Verify that the connection
>   information is correct and that you have permissions to access the
>   data source.http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=rsCannotRetrieveModel&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60Microsoft SQL
>   Server Reporting Services11.0.2100.60127OsIndependent1033ReportingServicesLibraryAn error
>   occurred while loading the model for the item or data source
>   'http://localhost/rpl/Model.bism'. Verify that the connection
>   information is correct and that you have permissions to access the
>   data
>   source.Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCoreCannot
>   impersonate user for data source
>   'TemporaryDataSource'.Microsoft.ReportingServices.ServiceRuntimeCannot
>   convert claims identity to windows
>   token.Microsoft.SharePointCould
>   not retrieve a valid Windows
>   identity.mscorlibAccess
>   is
>   denied.

Readable version

```
rsCannotRetrieveModel400An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source 'http://localhost/rpl/model.bism'. 
Verify that the connection information is correct and that you have permissions to access the data source.http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=rsCannotRetrieveModel&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services11.0.2100.60127OsIndependent1033ReportingServicesLibrary
An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source 'http://localhost/rpl/Model.bism'.
 Verify that the connection information is correct and that you have permissions to access the data source.Microsoft.ReportingServices.
ProcessingCoreCannot impersonate user for data source 'TemporaryDataSource'.
Microsoft.ReportingServices.

ServiceRuntimeCannot convert claims identity to windows token.Microsoft.SharePointCould not retrieve a valid Windows identity.mscorlib

Access is denied

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services11.0.2100.60127OsIndependent1033ReportingServicesLibrary
An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source 'http://localhost/rpl/Model.bism'.
 Verify that the connection information is correct and that you have permissions to access the data source.Microsoft.ReportingServices.
ProcessingCoreCannot impersonate user for data source 'TemporaryDataSource'.
Microsoft.ReportingServices.

ServiceRuntimeCannot convert claims identity to windows token.Microsoft.SharePointCould not retrieve a valid Windows identity.mscorlib

Access is denied
```

I am using SQL Server 2012 RTM, Sharepoint  2010, Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with service pack 1. All SQL, Analysis Services and Sharepoint windows services run with the same  domain account which is also administrator in local machine. That domain account is god in both SQL and Analysis Services. It also farm admin in sharepoint and all sharepoint services uses that account. IIS aplication pools run with that account too. I can connect by any other client like SQL Management Studio. What is wrong with Power View connection? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint central administration, Navigate to Application Management -> Manage Services on the Server. Stop the service "Claims to Windows Token Service" and restart IIS. Should fix your problem.