# An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source 'EntityDataSource'

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

I use `SQL Server 2012 SP1 U8` and `SharePoint 2013`.

I confiugure `Excel Service` and `Performance Point Service` and `PowerPivot Service` and ...

I create an `Excel File` that fetch data from `DataWare House` in `PowerPivot` report.

I load this file in `Documents` in my `Share Point Web Site`.

When I click on my excel file in SharePoint, I get this Error :

[image]

```
An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source 
'EntityDataSource'. Verify that the connection information is correct 
and that you have   permissions to access the data source.

<detail><ErrorCode xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
rsCannotRetrieveModel</ErrorCode><HttpStatus mlns=
"http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">400</HttpStatus>
<Message xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
An error occurred while loading the model for the item or data source
'EntityDataSource'. Verify that the connection information is correct and
that you have permissions to access the data source.</Message><HelpLink
xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;    
EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;
EvtID=rsCannotRetrieveModel&amp;ProdName=
Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.3401.0
</HelpLink><ProductName xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services</ProductName>
<ProductVersion xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">11.0.3401.0
</ProductVersion><ProductLocaleId xmlns
="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">127</ProductLocaleId>
<OperatingSystem xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
OsIndependent</OperatingSystem><CountryLocaleId   
xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
1033</CountryLocaleId><MoreInformationxmlns=
"http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
<Source>ReportingServicesLibrary</Source>
<Message msrs:ErrorCode="rsCannotRetrieveModel"     
msrs:HelpLink="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?
LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID
=rsCannotRetrieveModel&amp;ProdName=
Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.3401.0" 
xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">An error occurred 
while loading the model for the item or data source 'EntityDataSource'. 
Verify that the connection information is correct and that you have 
permissions to access the data source.</Message><MoreInformation>
<Source>Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore</Source><Message
 msrs:ErrorCode="rsErrorOpeningConnection" msrs:HelpLink=
"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;
EvtID=rsErrorOpeningConnection&amp;ProdName=
Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=11.0.3401.0" 
xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
Cannot create a connection to data source 'EntityDataSource'.
</Message><MoreInformation><Source>
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient</Source><Message>
We cannot locate a server to load the workbook Data Model.</Message>
<MoreInformation><Source></Source><Message>
We cannot locate a server to load the workbook Data Model.</Message>
<MoreInformation><Source>Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices
</Source><Message>We cannot locate a server to load the workbook Data Model.
</Message></MoreInformation></MoreInformation>
</MoreInformation></MoreInformation>
</MoreInformation>
<Warnings xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices" /></detail>
```

I see this [Power View Fails to Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862078/power-view-fails-to-connect) link and do this answer but it not work for me?

and this Link [PowerView Error: An error occurred while loading the model](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/64ca0546-f5c4-4d33-95c1-1cf17ac789de/powerview-error-an-error-occurred-while-loading-the-model-for-the-item-or-data-source?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Note : I can see all excel report that have not `PowerPivot` component.

Comment: Thai happening only if I use PowerPivot In Excel. Why you say : Remove Tag of PowerPivot?!?!

Comment: I didn't say anything about PowerPivot and you don't have it TAGGED with PowerPivot.  PowerPivot has nothing to do with PowerPoint, and you DO have it tagged for PowerPoint.